# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

I usually use this code to populate my listView but when I used this code when populating the application names installed in my device, I am getting an error from this code. Can you please help me and explain the solution for this?

**AdminActivity.java**

```
private void listviewItems() {
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist_AppDetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> hashmap = null;         
    int id = 1;

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        String appName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo);
        String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;

        if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)!= null && !pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName).equals("")){              hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();                
            hashmap.put(Constants.APP_NAME, appName);
            hashmap.put(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
            hashmap.put(Constants.ID, String.valueOf(id++));
            arraylist_AppDetails.add(hashmap);

            Log.i("arraylist_AppDetails", String.valueOf(arraylist_AppDetails));
        }
    } 

    ListView lv_InstalledApp = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_InstalledApp);
    CustomAdapter_InstalledApps installAppsAdapter = new CustomAdapter_InstalledApps(
            AdminActivity.this, arraylist_AppDetails,
            R.layout.attribute_applist,
            Constants.APPDATA_ATTRIBUTE_KEYS,
            Constants.APPDATA_ATTRIBUTES_VIEWS, true);
    lv_InstalledApp.setAdapter(installAppsAdapter);
}
```

**customAdapter.java**

```
private Context context;
private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mData;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> unfilteredValues;
private boolean chosenValues, ismarkAll = true;
private int resource;
private String[] from;
private int[] to;
private SimpleFilter mFilter;
private ArrayList<String> arraylistAppId;
private ArrayList<String> arraylistAppSelected;

private final boolean[] mCheckedState;

public CA_InstalledApps(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource,
        String[] from, int[] to, boolean chosenValues) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    mCheckedState = new boolean[data.size()];

    this.context = context;
    mData = data;
    this.unfilteredValues = mData;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.arraylistAppId = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.arraylistAppSelected = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.chosenValues = chosenValues;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final int pos = position;
    // View rowView = null;
    try {
        // if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null, true);
        TextView tv_C_ID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[0]);
        TextView tv_C_APPNAME = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[1]);
        TextView tv_C_PACKAGENAME = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(to[2]);

        String C_ID = from[0];
        String C_APPNAME = from[1];
        String C_PACKAGENAME = from[2];

        // getting the value in hashmap
        final String _id = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(C_ID)
                .toString();
        String _appname = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(C_APPNAME)
                .toString();
        String _packagename = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(C_PACKAGENAME)
                .toString();


        tv_C_ID.setText(_id);
        tv_C_APPNAME.setText(_appname);
        tv_C_PACKAGENAME.setText(_packagename);

        // Setting the ID
        tv_C_ID.setId(position);
        tv_C_APPNAME.setId(position);
        tv_C_PACKAGENAME.setId(position);

        // }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}

   // Other codes from here....
```

**Logcat**

```
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3698)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3693)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     ... 11 more
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.example.kioskmode.AdminActivity.listviewItems(AdminActivity.java:142)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.example.kioskmode.AdminActivity.viewInstalledApps(AdminActivity.java:100)
01-23 09:39:01.964: E/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.example.kioskmode.AdminActivity.onButtonClicked(AdminActivity.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IllegalStateException` is the most outer one, but you see from the `Caused by:` clauses that the root exception is a `NullPointerException` happening on line 142 of your `S_2nd_AdminActivity.java` file in `S_2nd_AdminActivity.listviewItems()`.
This NPE is then escalated and the Android framework classes eventually throw an `IllegalStateException`.

As for what's causing the NPE, is line 142 this one:

```
hashmap.put(Constants.APP_NAME, appName);
```

? You seem to never affect any valid `Map` instance to the `hashmap` variable which in the code you pasted would still be `null` when executing the above instruction. `null` can't be dereferenced and the VM would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: edited my answer - if it doesn't seem right and you still can't figure it out, please provide line numbers (or which one is l.142).

Comment: oooh, I got it. Now, my problem is how can I get each appName and packageName so that I could access it..

Comment: well you seem to be doing it already right, getting a list of `PackageInfo` and iterating through it. If the `null` `hashmap` reference was actually your problem, just affect it a new `HashMap` before trying to add data in it: insert `hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();` at line 142. Otherwise you should open a new question as this is a different problem.